# How can I set up Emacs for use with Python with debugging and cross referencing?

Tags: python

I see a lot of links about lsp-mode, and have worked through the elpy setup `https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html`

This is about getting emacs to do debugging in editor. The question I have is about how to actually get lsp-mode to work with python applications like flask/django frameworks (focus on flask for the specifics of this question), or if not lsp-mode, a better solution.

Comment: The question is too broad, and encourages opinion-based answers, each of which is likely to be broad. A suggestion is to google or ask at a discussion sites such as Reddit for such recommendations. This site is more for specific how-to Q & A.

Comment: As already @Drew mentioned before the question is too broad, but take a look a this video, it could help. (probably you already saw it, but is really help full) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-NAM9U5JYE&list=PLEoMzSkcN8oPH1au7H6B7bBJ4ZO7BXjSZ&index=8

Comment: That's helpful @baezacaljo, I'll work through it.

Comment: Yes to broad but take a look at the Videos of SystemCrafters aka David Wilson. e.g. https://youtu.be/jPXIP46BnNA . Currently myself I work on moving away from `elpy` back to a more Emacs inbuild python support using language server (`lsp-mode`). But I am not finished yet. It would be great if you could show us your solution even if it does not work yet.